# Add link in PDF with target="_blank" using Zend_pdf

Tags: php, zend-framework, pdf, target

My code:

> $page->drawText('Text', 80, 576, 'utf-8');
>
> $target     = Zend_Pdf_Action_URI :: create( 'http://www.stackoverflow.com');
>
> $annotation = Zend_Pdf_Annotation_Link :: create( 0, 0, 0, 0, $target);
>
> $page->attachAnnotation( $annotation );

i'm creating a PDF file with a link and I need to open the link in a new window. 
How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

An URI action does not allow you to define that the target should be opened in a new window. This is a PDF sepcific behavior.
Other actions like "Launch" have a "NewWindow" flag but this will only get attention if the document is opened in the Reader application and not through a browser plugin.